# Reading values separated by commas in Python

Tags: python

Say if I had a function which takes several integers such as 
("22, 3, 2") and ("3, -8, , 3) as parameters.

Is it possible, and how if possible, to individually check and read each value separated by commas.

Comment: you're passing them as a string or just as a lot of arguments?

Comment: Have you tried something already? Please give us something to work with, apart from a question.

Comment: parse through them by splitting on `,` but what have you tried? This is rather simple and a quick google could yield you many answers

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems are you facing?

Comment: If it's a just a string, use `somestring.split(",")`

Comment: _"a function which takes several integers such as..."_. `("22, 3, 2")` is not an integer or a collection of integers. It is a single string surrounded by a superfluous pair of parentheses. `("3, -8, , 3)` isn't an integer or a collection of integers. It's not syntactically valid Python at all, since there's no second quote mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your parameter to function is a string with comma delimiter you can use split function:

```
my_data = '22, 3, 2'
parsed = my_data.split(',')
print(parsed) # ['22', ' 3', ' 2']
```

If you would like to have list of tuples you can use:

```
print(tuple(parsed)) # ('22', ' 3', ' 2')
```

Comment: @Kevin - thanks I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a split, split takes in a "separator" and breaks the string down into an array using the "separator" as an end point:

```
words = '22, 3, 2'
words2 = words.split(',')
```

**Examples/information:**
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split

Comment: The quotes used in your example are invalid. Also you are not adding any valuable info to the already existing answer.

Comment: Now `word` is an undefined variable.    `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'word' is not defined`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thanks for pointing it out